# Encoding a PHP script in UTF-8 gives funny characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I've changed the encoding of the PHP script (as in the encoding of the actual .php file) to UTF-8, which I did by convert encoding in Notepad++, and this has resulted in `ï»¿` being echoed at the beginning of the script. I can't get rid of it. I can't see any such characters in the script. I even tried copy & pasting into a new file but it's still there.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Change encoding to UTF-8 __WITHOUT__ BOM and then save again

Comment: ï»¿ this is UTF8-bom signature :(

Comment: Create new file in UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM and after put there a text

Comment: OK, thanks guys. Someone please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments `ï»¿` is the UTF-8 bom signature:

> Change encoding to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM and then save again